# Codeigniter set two base url in config for desktop site and mobile site?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, url-routing

Codeigniter set two base URL in the config for the desktop site and a mobile site?
I like site name https://www.example.com for desktop and https://m/example.com for the mobile sites.
I have changed only view files for the mobile sites using the mobile user-agent library but controller and models are the same. Please help me I want to redirect automatically when the site opens in a mobile device.

Comment: `using the mobile user-agent library` - what library? Does it do mobile agent detection? If yes, why not use it to set a different base URL?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I trying to update config file but  which code is defined for base_url in the config file, the site is mobile or desktop.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Please edit your question and add some details about what you are doing.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I want to code for detect mobile device in config file then I add mobile site URL.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I redirect www subdomain to m subdomain for mobile site

Comment: I know this does not address your question, but why do people still use separate mobile versions (which are not good for SEO) instead of just going responsive? In the not-so-long run, going Responsive is faster, easier, better for SEO and maintaining the site in the future is less work too

Comment: @JavierLarroulet We have using the same title and meta detail only URL redirect in mobile from m.

Comment: @ChirayuVyas it's still bad for SEO. Search engine crawlers nowadays are able to determine if the site is mobile friendly or if there's two different sites (one for mobile and one for desktop). The former will always position better in search engines than the latter. SEO aside, it's more work (to implement and maintain) to keep a separate set of views (even if the controller is the same) instead of using a mobile-first approach with bootstrap or similar css frameworks

Comment: By the way, without altering Codeigniter's core, what you're attempting to do is very very complex. According to the way CI orchestrates, the base URL is set many steps before the user agent library is initialized, so that would not be the way to go

Comment: @JavierLarroulet Our site have the same content and same things only difference of view, other similar sites have both URL and sites top-ranked on google.

Comment: @JavierLarroulet we found solution using htaccess we redirect on m site.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your `config/config.php` file

```
       <?php
       defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

       /*
       |-------------------------------------------------------------------------           -
       | Base Site URL
       |-------------------------------------------------------------------------           - 
       */

       $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
       if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
       {
           //Set The Base Url
           $config['base_url'] = 'https://www.example.com/';
           //Redirect To The Url
           header("Location: https://www.example.com/");
       }
       else
       {
           //Set The Base Url
           $config['base_url'] = 'https://mobi.example.com/';
           //Redirect To The Url 
           header("Location: https://mobi.example.com ");
       }
```